# Dynamic Adding item to list with different list and different adapter

Tags: android

how can I add item to list adapter, but every time I iterate n, it will add to a different list and different adapter, thanks!

//my first code

```
int n = 1;
            while (n != 16) {

                Day(n, Fullname);
                n +=1 ;
            }
```

//the other one that will add to the list and adapter

```
 private void Day(int n,String Fullname){
    String Date = "0" + n + "-" + Month + "-" + Year;
    Cursor c = db.GetSpecific(Fullname,Date);
    String allowancecount = "";
    int intallowancecount = 0;
    double totalCom = 0;
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String serviceprice = c.getString(4);
        String serviceperformedbynumber = c.getString(10);
        allowancecount = c.getString(12);
        intallowancecount = intallowancecount + Integer.parseInt(allowancecount.trim());
        double income = Integer.parseInt(serviceprice.trim())/
                Integer.parseInt(serviceperformedbynumber.trim());
        totalCom = totalCom + income ;
        //here what to do?
        String add ="List" + n + ".add(String.valueOf(" + income  + "));";
        do add;//???????
    }
    //here what to do?
    String Dynamic = "Com" + n + ".setText(String.valueOf(" + totalCom + "))";
    do Dynamic ;//?????????

    String Dynamicadapter = "Lv" + n + ".setAdapter(adapter" + n + ")";
    do Dynamicadapter ;//????????
}
```

i'm just thinking if this was possible, but if not, i'll do it on the other way i know,open for any suggestions, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible in Java to assign variable using a variable name. However, there are things that you can use for these types of situations which allow you to almost do this, but everything is created correctly at runtime without the need for dynamic behaviour. For example, you can think about this in terms of using an `associative array`.

Taken from Wikipedia -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(mapping)#Java

> In Java associative arrays are implemented as "maps"; they are part of
>   the Java collections framework. Since J2SE 5.0 and the introduction of
>   generics into Java, collections can have a type specified; for
>   example, an associative array mapping strings to strings might be
>   specified

So in light of this, you could use a `Map` and restructure your code to do the following:

1. Create your adapter object
2. Set it's properties (such as `setAdapter()`)
3. Add it to the map by using `i` (or whatever you want to use as a `key` for this)
4. Access it later on from the `map` using the `key`/dynamic 'variable name'

```
Map<Integer, ArrayAdapter<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayAdapter<String>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  map.put(i, yourAdapter);
}
```